# Where is the brunch adapter for Grunt tasks

Tags: gruntjs, brunch

On [brunch website](http://brunch.io/#why), it states that brunch "even has an adapter for Grunt tasks".

It is not documented anywhere, neither could I find any reference to grunt on brunch source code.

Has anybody ever experimented this feature ? How does it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the after-brunch plugin or an `onCompile` hook in your config to execute arbitrary commands or functions after each brunch compile cycle, including commands for running grunt tasks.

Comment: Seems more like a workaround than an actual "adapter", but yea, works anyway !